# Reverse oxidative phosphorylation?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, metabolism, energy-metabolism

I noticed that all of the cellular energy production methods that I covered have a fixed ratio of ATP to NAD(P)H out. For example, in the combined process of glycolysis, pyruvate oxidization, and the Krebs cycle, 10 NADH, 2 FADH2, and 4 ATP are produced (based off of my high school's bio text book, if I'm adding that right). In this way, NADH and FADH2 can easily be exchanged for ATP through oxidative phosphorylation. That got me wondering what would happen if a cell was using so many electrons (from NADH and/or FADH2) that there is *too much* ATP. (Just as a hypothetical: It seems fairly unlikely to me)

I was looking for a way that oxidative phosphorylation could be reversed, but I didn't find much. I did find that anaerobic bacteria can [oxidize nitrite](https://academic.oup.com/femsre/article/4/4/259/559333) in this way, but I couldn't find much evidence of an O2-forming version. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I am not clear whether you understand how ATP is produced in oxidative phosphorylation when you talk about producing oxygen. If you are still following a course you should wait until you have learned how a proton gradient, produced by the oxidative electron transport chain, is used to phosphorylate ADP. When you are at that stage you will be in a position to appreciate how hydrogen ion transport can be accomplished by essentially the reverse of this process. (If you need to learn this yourself, we can suggest suitable reading.)

Comment: Sorry, should've clarified... My question is basically whether there is a mechanism in any organism to split H2O (into H+ and O2, like PSII) using energy from an existing H+ gradient, possibly created by an ATPase.

Comment: I cannot see any biological rationale for what you are suggesting (much less any chemical likelihood), but I should point out that the production of ATP (like other biochemical processes) is tightly regulated. If there is sufficient ATP, there will be a switch from energy generation to energy storage.